# Find minimum accessed records in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I had a table which contains `id, name and address` and the table may contains 1000's of records. Now I wants to make a backup for least(minimum) accessed records which may be 1 month older. The older record is selected based on its access. The **main table** only contains *frequently* accessed records. Is it possible to find least accessed records in mysql (Query)???

Comment: Is there any ways you can rephrase it with more context/better phrasing for non-english users?

Comment: you can minus your main table with the table which has all the records. In case of mysql use sub-query to achieve minus.

Comment: @divyabharathi How can i check which record is accessed minimum number of time